# How to position an element relative to the background image width

Tags: html, css

Note: I do not have JS access. This must be done with CSS.

I have a background image (850 x 1080) positioned at the bottom right of the screen. I have the image scaled so that it takes up 38% of the width:

```
background-position: right bottom;
background-size: 38% auto;
background-attachment: fixed;
```

Now I want to position another element such that it always, regardless of the screen size, lines up with a certain part of the background image. How would I go about that? I currently have it set at a set distance away from the right and bottom edge, but this is not what I want:

```
height: 220px;
width: 155px;
bottom: 400px;
right: 400px;
```

[My code can be found here](https://gist.github.com/abdullahfahad/08f06c781ffb72fcb53e), and the part I'm trying to position is in the definition of `:hover + .hide` (line 12). The page I'm trying to customize is my [MyAnimeList profile](http://myanimelist.net/animelist/Wyverncloak), where I'm trying to line up the cover art with the edge of the red sword-looking thing.

Comment: Something like this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11151089/position-one-element-related-to-another-in-css"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the background size changes according to the width of it's container, you can use percent margin to position the element. Percent Margins are calculated according to the width of the container, even top/bottom margin ([see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin#Values)).

example :

```
:hover + .hide{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    margin-bottom:20%; /* tune this */
    margin-right:20%; /* tune this */
}
```

Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/tu8grLL4/)**

Comment: Is there a way to make the margin-bottom dependent on the margin-right, since I have the height of the background set to auto?

Comment: @Wyverncloak as I said in th answer, margin bottom and right are both calculated according to the width of the cotainer so if for example you set them both to `20%` they will both have the same value in `px` calculated according to the parent's width.

Comment: I understand that bit, I meant if I wanted margin-bottom to be 1.2 times whatever margin-right came out to be in pixels. If margin-right: 20% came out to be 100px for that screen, I want to make margin-bottom 120px.

Comment: @Wyverncloak well if `margin-right: 20%;` then `margin-bottom = 20% * 1.2 = 24%`

Comment: If the surrounding container is 800 x 1000, that would come out to be 160 x 240, as opposed to 160 x (160 * 1.2), which would be 160 x 192.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63773/discussion-between-web-tiki-and-wyverncloak).