# How to position an element relative to a specific background image object?

Tags: html, css

I have a background image with some objects like a company logo. This image is a full screen background and I want to align an element with the company logo and make it responsive.

I have searched for some similar solutions and tried using a solution proposed in this link: 
[How to position an element relative to the background image width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26606005/how-to-position-an-element-relative-to-the-background-image-width)

Although I am able to position the element correctly, it doesn't remain in the same place relative to the image when the screen is resized.

How can I keep this html element always aligned?

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("http://www.rizwanashraf.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/11/mac-wallapers-13.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.container{
  position: relative;
}

.fixed-title{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin: 28% 0 0 54%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="fixed-title">Apple</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: @LucianoFCastelfranchi I am trying to avoid this because in the future the background images will be random and the logo will change maybe its colors, for instance. Plus, in this exemple i just have one logo to keep it simple but i have multiple objects to align like a login form for exemple. The login form gets align with another background object and I cannot afford to start removing everything from the background image. I also want to know if this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Coupled with what I wrote below, this should be what you're after :) All that is left to do is change the percentages to match the position you're after. If you need to move something in px you can use `calc()` css function to do

> height: calc(100% - 100px);

This would make your thing 100% of the height - 100px.

```css
body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position:relative
      background-image: url("http://www.rizwanashraf.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/11/mac-wallapers-13.jpg");
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: 0 0;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
.title-container{
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left:50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
    }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="title-container">
    <h1>My Title</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

It looks like you are halfway there already having used `postionion:absolute` already.

I would suggest instead of using `margin:28% 0 0 54%` to look into using the `transform` property coupled with `translateX()` and `translateY()` or the shorthand version `translate( , );`.

The solution below puts your title in the very center of the container.

```css
.fixed-title{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
}
```

This solution only centers your h1 on the Y axis (up and down)

```css
.fixed-title{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%); 
}
```

This solution only centers your h1 on the X axis (left and right)

```css
.fixed-title{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%); 
}
```

Hopefully this helps :)

P.s. Here is a link to a great article on all the uses for the `transform` property : https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/

Comment: I tried your solution but the title still moves its position when the screen resizes. By the way great article on transform, thank you!

Comment: @TiagoConceiçao -- I've updated my answer. Does this help?