# How to vertically align something with the element in front of its parent

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-float, vertical-alignment

Given this html:

```
<header>Some header</header>
<div>
    <div class="right-of-header">should be to the right of header</div>
    <div>Some mor text is here</div>
</div>
```

I want the content of the first inner div appear to the right, of the header.

Is this possible, without using javascript to actually move the DOM element?

I just found this question: [Position one element relative to another in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11151089/position-one-element-related-to-another-in-css) but this won't work for me, since I don't know the size and width of the header element. In other words, the solution should be responsive to different layouts.

There is a [jsfiddle for it here](https://jsfiddle.net/ex17ak9x/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works: https://jsfiddle.net/djgmj89c/

The idea is to

1. Make the `float: left`
2. Make the content that should go to the right of it `float: right;`
3. Make the element after the one that should go to the right `clear: both;`

Resulting in the following css:

```
header {
    float: left;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
.right-of-header {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: no, this is just right aligned. I want it on the same vertical position, but to the right of the header. I updated the fiddle to include an example how it should look like.

Comment: I used your approach and cleaned up your answer. I hope the drastic edit is ok with you.

Comment: In the version I actually use, replaced the `clear` class with this: `header+* :not(.right-of-header):first-of-type {
    clear: both;
}`

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that a div has it's default `display` set to `block`.

My suggestion is to modify your html. Change the **display** value of your `header` to `display: inline-block;` and your `right-of-header` to `display: inline;`.

as follow:

```
<style>
header {
    font-size: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.right-of-header {
    font-size: 8px;
    width: 50px;
    display: inline;
}
</style>

<header>Some header</header>
<div class="right-of-header">should be to the right of header</div>
<div>
    <div>Some mor text is here</div>
</div>
```

Here a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/z1c9Lgzo/

**EDIT:**

As you can't modify your html, another solution ***(which I'm totally against it, but can't seem to find another way)*** would be to alter the `position` relatively. Like so:

```
.right-of-header {
    font-size: 8px;
    width: 50px;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: -40px;
}
```

Here a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/g4srpcpn/

You might need to tweek the `top` value for better alignment.

Comment: Unfortunatly I can't move the div element. Well I could but that would create issues in other places ...

Comment: I added another answer. To be honest, as explained, I'm not a fan of altering positions for alignment  issues.

Comment: I understand and agree to your concerns, but this seems to a viable option.

Answer (score 1):

if you have a parent container with position relative maybe this can help you.

```
<header>Some header</header>
<div>
    <div class="right-of-header">should be to the right of header</div>
    <div>Some mor text is here</div>
</div>

<style>
header {
    font-size: 30px;
    display: inline-block
}

header + div{
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}

header + div > div:nth-of-type(2){
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    padding: 10px;
}

.right-of-header {
    font-size: 8px;
    width: 50px;
}
</style>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0wqud60n/1/