# How to position a popup beside the button that triggered it with css and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

I am currently dynamically creating x number of divs and within each div, I have a button that shows a popup whenever clicked.

I am trying to position the button below the specific button that triggered it but the position of the popup is always static for a reason, it does not move below the button.

```
<div className="popWrap">
    <div className="popup" id="pop" style={{display: 'none'}}>
            <Card className="myCardStyle"> 
               <CardHeader>hello</CardHeader>
               <CardBody>body</CardBody>
            </Card>
    </div>  
    <button className="myBtn" onClick={this.displayBtn}>View Button Info</button>
</div>
```

Here is my css:

```
.myCardStyle {
width: 100%;
 }

.popup {
   z-index: 10000;
 }

.popwrap{
   border:1px solid pink;
   padding:1px;
   position: inherit;
   display:inline-block;
 }
```

Anyone can suggest a solution?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please create a proper [mre].

Comment: Duplicate: [Position one element relative to another in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11151089/position-one-element-relative-to-another-in-css)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add `position: relative;` to the `.popWrap` div. Then you can set `position: absolute;` to the `.popup` element and give it a specific (top) position to move it where you want it to be.

Example:

```
.popup {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50px;
   z-index: 10000;
 }

.popWrap {
   position: relative;
   border: 1px solid pink;
   padding: 1px;
   display: inline-block;
 }
```

Comment: By the way, you are targeting `.popwrap` in your CSS. But it has a capital W in your HTML code. So in your CSS code you should also use it like that: `.popWrap {`.  And the `className=""` should be `class=""`.

Comment: Please check for dupes before answering: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11151089/position-one-element-relative-to-another-in-css